# How to store image path in database - using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, base64

currently i can store file name is database and in public folder of laravel but i want to store file path in database?

My Controller:

```
$image=$userProfile['image'];
$image1 = base64_decode($image);
$filename = time().'.'.$extension;
Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,$image1);
$this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profile_pic' => $filename]);
```

How i can store image path in laravel and image name in public folder? i am sending image in json using base64.

Your help will be highly appreciated?

Comment: You should put path with name like `['profile_pic' => $filePath.$filename]` eventhough I don't recommend to store the path in the DB in case it changes later. If it changes you have to modify all records.

Comment: can you edit in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$image = $userProfile['image'];
$image1 = base64_decode($image);
$filename = time().'.'.$extension;
Storage::disk('public')->put($filename,$image1);    
$filePath = Storage::disk('public')->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
$this->user->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['profile_pic' => $filePath.$filename]);
```

Comment: From where did you get the variable $extension ?

Answer (score 0):

First type this command :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

it will create a symlink to public folder.

in your controller, you can write like this :

```
if ($request->file('image')) {
    $file = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
    $new_product->image = $file;
 }
```

this code will insert a random string included the path, so you can have something like this on your image column value 'images/shgsqwerfsd.jpg'